# How to load external application.yml into the app developed with Micronaut Picocli?

Tags: micronaut, picocli

- Java: 11.0.7
- Micronaut: 2.1.2
- Micronaut profile: cli-app

I have an application developed with micronaut framework in cli-app profile. My application uses Hibernate and GORM packages, so there are relevant configurations in application.yml

In the default configuration, micronaut load application.yml from src/main/resources.

If I want my application load application.yml from the arguments like below:

```
java -Dmicronaut.config=/etc/fooApp/application.yml -jar fooApp.jar
```

How should I do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can provide additional configuration files using `micronaut.config.files` system property. You can define it either using `-D` or by exporting the `MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES` environment variable.

#### A variant with the `-D` system property option

```sh
java -Dmicronaut.config.files=/etc/fooApp/application.yml -jar fooApp.jar
```

#### A variant with the inlined environment variable

```sh
MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES=/etc/fooApp/application.yml java -jar fooApp.jar
```

#### A variant with the exported environment variable

```sh
export MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES=/etc/fooApp/application.yml

java -jar fooApp.jar
```

When you provide an additional configuration file with this technique, all values defined in the `/etc/fooApp/application.yml` will take precedence over values defined in e.g. `classpath:application.yml` file. If you want to control a specific order, you will need to define comma-separated configuration files. For instance, if you want to provide an additional configuration file, but you want to take the precedence of the `classpath:application.yml` file, then you need to do the following:

```sh
java -Dmicronaut.config.files=/etc/fooApp/application.yml,classpath:application.yml -jar fooApp.jar
```

More information: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#propertySource

---

⚠️ **ATTENTION:** If you want to hardcode this `/etc/fooApp.application.yml` location to your CLI application, you can execute

```java
System.setProperty("micronaut.config.files", "/etc/fooApp/application.yml");
```

in the `main()` method of the CLI application class. However, you will get `ConfigurationException` if the file does not exist, so keep in mind that you might need to do some additional checks if you decide to go with this approach. I did something similar in the `stackoverflow-cli` application [to store an access token](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js5H9UbmmMY&t=1210s) and inject it later to the declarative HTTP client.